# Does the distribution of a Mongo field's values affect index performance?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

If an indexed field in a Mongo collection has a distribution that is not be uniform, for example having a common prefix

```
{
  field: 'systemID_4628937419',
  ...
}
{
  field: 'systemID_0189347591',
  ...
}
```

are there performance implications compared to a field with uniformly distributed values?

---

I could imagine an index uses some transformed/hashed values so regardless of the distribution of real values, the values the index operates on are nicely distributed, but I don't know.

Or perhaps it doesn't even need to, and the distribution of values just doesn't affect performance that much.

Comment: The only thing I can see here is that the `systemID_` is totally redundant. Indices are lists of key value pairs, lexicographically sorted by key in ascending or descending order. Technically, the difference between `"#:€) 83/!9@&93/"` and `"abcdefghijklmn"` (note the quotes!) is negligible for all practical purposes in this regard.

Comment: Agreed that `systemID_` is redundant, but say these values are coming from a system over which I don't have control, like some external API. Your point is that the actual values don't really matter, just the order? So having `systemID_` does NOT hurt index performance?

Comment: Will it impact performance one way or the other? Probably. Will it be measurable or even noticable? Hardly. Maybe somewhere in the nano to maybe microsecond area. For comparison: that’s 1/1000000 of a second and sending the result set over the network takes several hundred to several thousand times longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type of value for an _id field (except for Arrays). Best option (cause is the default mongo implementation) is to use **ObjectId**.

If you choose not to use ObjectId, you'll have to somehow guarantee uniqueness of values.

If you check (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) and it's hex representation there is in fact 12 bytes of difference, the ObjectId being 12 bytes and any other string _id hex representation being 24.

Object_id has more *storage efficiency* and also can be used in a special manner to ensure that only parts of the index are loaded; the parts that are used. This becomes most noticeable when inserting, where only the latest part of that index needs to be loaded in to ensure uniqueness.